# Bash bitcoin blockchain explorer

Tags: performance, json, bash, cryptocurrency, blockchain

I wrote a little bash script that displays the transaction info in json:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -o errexit

function process_block() {
  date --rfc-3339=ns
  bhash=${1:-$(bitcoin-cli getbestblockhash)}
  block=$(bitcoin-cli getblock $bhash)
  pbhash=$(echo "$block" | jq -r .previousblockhash)
  height=$(echo "$block" | jq -r .height)
  echo "height: $height"
  nTx=$(echo "$block" | jq -r .nTx)
  echo "$nTx transactions"
  Tx=$(echo "$block" | jq -r .tx[])
  IFS=$'\n'
  for txhash in $Tx; do
    txjson=$(bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction $txhash 1 $bhash)
    addresses=$(echo "$txjson" | jq -r '.vout[].scriptPubKey | select(.type == "pubkeyhash") | .addresses | .[]')
    for a in $addresses; do
      if [[ $a == ${2} ]]; then
        echo "$txjson"
      fi
    done
  done
  process_block $pbhash ${2}
}

process_block "" ${1}
```

Can be used as:

```bsh
./btc.sh 1...
```

I ran bitcoind in pruned mode to get a blockchain. I downloaded the latest snapshot like this:

```bsh
aria2c http://utxosets.blob.core.windows.net/public/$(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-docker/master/contrib/FastSync/utxo-sets | grep -F mainnet | tail -n 1 | grep -Po utxo.*)
```

The only problem is that it is really slow.  It takes about a minute to process about 1k transactions.  Any advice how the things could be speed up?

Comment: I am currently rebuilding the whole blockchain with **-txindex** option.  But I don't know how many days/weeks it can take.

Comment: Wait a second.  Actually I was rebuilding with **-reindex** option and **-txindex** is incompatible with prune mode.  I interrupted the process to check it out, then resumed it and it is started from the beginning of the blockchain basically ruining 3 days of servers's work.  I guess I have to wait till the end without any interruption with **-reindex** option to see if it will help..

Comment: Nah.  It is unlikely it will help anyhow w/o txindex.  I should probably find other ways how to speed up my explorer.

Comment: Alright.  We got getblock with verbosity = 2 here. :) https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12651#issuecomment-527418478